# github auto-deployment for static websites

Tags: git, github, deployment, web-deployment, devops

We have a lot of small static sites that we maintain. We manage our projects on GitHub.

I'm currently looking for standard ways to automatically deploy to a linux server with minimal manual steps involved.

I currently find the following solution:

1. a git push triggers a webhook in github (a specific label signals the prod. server to update)
2. GitHub calls the production server via the webhook
3. A small nodejs app listens on the production server for the hook and triggers a git pull

The disadvantage that I see, it that I need to open & secure a port (involving IP tables, filtering etc) on a production server.

Is there another way of doing this? I highly doubt that there is no lightweight out of the box solution (I don't want to setup a CI server like Jenkins, Bamboo etc).

Thanks
Christian

Comment: You can script a regular "git pull" (or whatever the command is to see if there is any changes) and if there were any changes continue with your deployment.  Both Windows and Linux allow for scheduling tasks.  This will work with any git repository, not just only github.

Comment: Thanks @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, that's for sure a straight-forward solution, also easy to setup, but I don't want to cause unnessesary traffic all the time.

Comment: `git pull` won't really download anything if there is nothing new to get from the server. Of course you will need to keep the `.git` directory on the server to avoid having to get the whole repo on every pull.

Comment: @mostafazh it's okay for me to have the full repo cloned

Comment: Any reason you can’t just have your server as a remote?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using AWS...

**(Serverless)** Hosting your static website on **S3/CloudFront** as suggested is cheap, fast(CDN) and you don't have to worry about scaling yourself. Just be careful, you have to upload your website via **AWS CLI** using ***aws s3 sync*** or use your own upload script that assigns or guesses correct mime types of the files.

**(24/7 server)** answering your original question, since some still require their own server. I recommend using CodePipeline with GitHub integration, CodeBuild(If needed) and CodeDeploy.

Quick summary of the process

- Create a new **CodePipeline** (1$/month after trial period)
- Create a Github source in **CodePipeline** and go through the login process and repo selection.
- (Optional) Pass source artifact to **CodeBuild** to build your code (npm build..etc)
- (Optional) I recommend a manual approve step in **CodePipeline** for production deployments. You can leave it fully automated for your testing environment if you wish.
- Pass the built artifact to **CodeDeploy** to be deployed to your EC2 instance or autoscaling target group. You define your CodeDeploy deployment process by including the **appspec file** inside your source code.
- Set up **SNS** notifications for deployment failures at least.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you already have your production server. But did you ever consider hosting those static websites on AWS S3? it's very very cheap and very reliable.

I'd also recommend taking a look at CircleCI which can deploy any changes to your github repos to S3 automatically and for FREE.

Take a look at those 2 blog posts: [here](http://benlopatin.com/deploying-static-sites-circle-ci/) and [here](https://eftakhairul.com/automate-static-website-deployment-on-aws-s3-using-circleci/).

Comment: thanks mostafazh very interesting, I will have a look into it! Im primarily looking for a solution, without a 3rd-party involved.